I'm not able to create propper essential matrices and I don't know why
I'm currently trying to generate an essential matrix from two cameras with known parameters. According to Wikipedia this can easily be done by calculating the transformation ($R$, $\vec{t}$) from one camera ($c1$) to the other ($c2$) and using the results to build the essential matrix. To be more specific, given a transformation:
$x_{c2} = R \cdot (x_{c1} - \vec{t})$
The essential matrix can be created like this:
$E = R \cdot [\vec{t}]_\times$
where $[\vec{t}]_\times$ is the matrix representation of the cross product with the translation vector $\vec{t}$.
This Essential matrix $E$ has some special properties:

its determinant is zero ($det(E) = 0$)
for all point-correspondences between $c1$ and $c2$, the following equation should be true: $x_{c2}^T E x_{c1} = 0$
there should be one eigenvalue for $E$ that is zero, and the other two eigenvalues should be equal.

The reason why I mention these properties here, is because I can't find an essential matrix that fulfills them using the formulas above. I created a small Python script that does exactly what i described above:
def essential_matrix_tests(r1, t1, k1, r2, t2, k2, Pw):
    # projected points
    prj1 = k1 @ np.concatenate((r1, t1), axis=1)  # camera 1 world to image projection matrix
    prj2 = k2 @ np.concatenate((r2, t2), axis=1)  # camera 2 world to image projection matrix
    Pc_1 = r1 @ Pw[:, :3] + t1  # world points transformed into camera 1 space
    Pc_2 = r2 @ Pw[:, :3] + t2  # world points transformed into camera 2 space
    Pi_1 = prj1 @ Pw  # world points projected into camera 1 image space
    Pi_1 /= Pi_1[:, 2:]  # dehomogenize
    Pi_2 = prj2 @ Pw  # world points projected into camera 2 image space
    Pi_2 /= Pi_2[:, 2:]  # dehomogenize
    # print projected points
    print("-> world points:", np.squeeze(Pw[:, :3]),
          "-> camera-space 1:", np.round(Pc_1.squeeze(), decimals=3),
          "-> camera-space 2:", np.round(Pc_2.squeeze(), decimals=3),
          "-> image-space 1:", np.round(Pi_1[:, :2].squeeze(), decimals=1),
          "-> image-space 2:", np.round(Pi_2[:, :2].squeeze(), decimals=1),
          sep="\n")
    # essential matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_matrix#Derivation_and_definition)
    R = r2 @ r1.T  # camera 1 to camera 2 rotation
    t = t1 - R.T @ t2  # camera 1 to camera 2 translation
    Tx = np.array([[0, -t[2, 0], t[1, 0]],  # cross product matrix of translation
                   [t[2, 0], 0, -t[0, 0]],
                   [-t[1, 0], t[0, 0], 0]], dtype=float)
    E = R @ Tx  # create essential matrix
    # check essential matrix properties (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_matrix#Properties)
    Pn_1 = Pc_1 / Pc_1[:, 2:]  # normalized points in camera 1 space
    Pn_2 = Pc_2 / Pc_2[:, 2:]  # normalized points in camera 2 space
    eigen_vals = np.linalg.eigvals(E)
    print("-> essential matrix:", np.round(E, decimals=3),
          "-> determinant:", np.round(np.linalg.det(E), decimals=3),
          "-> eigen values:", np.round(eigen_vals, decimals=8),
          "-> absolute eigen values:", np.round(np.abs(eigen_vals), decimals=6),
          "-> epipolar constraint for all points:", np.round(np.sum(Pn_2.swapaxes(1, 2) @ E @ Pn_1), decimals=3),
          sep="\n")
    # using opencv to reconstruct pose (only works if both camera matrices are equal)
    if np.allclose(k1, k2):
        _, R_reconstructed, t_reconstructed, _ = cv.recoverPose(E, Pi_1[:, :2].squeeze(), Pi_2[:, :2].squeeze(), k1)
        t_reconstructed *= np.linalg.norm(t)
        print("-> rotation (rotvec in degrees):",
              np.round(Rotation.from_matrix(R).as_rotvec(degrees=True), decimals=3),
              "-> reconstructed rotation (rotvec in degrees):",
              np.round(Rotation.from_matrix(R_reconstructed).as_rotvec(degrees=True), decimals=3),
              "-> translation:", np.round(t.squeeze(), decimals=3),
              "-> reconstructed translation:", np.round(t_reconstructed.squeeze(), decimals=3),
              sep="\n")

This function takes the rotation matrix, translation vector and camera matrix of two cameras, as well as some 3D points in world coordinates and calculates the essential matrix and the projected points in the camera coordinate systems and the image spaces of each camera. At the end I also calculate the determinant, eigenvalues and use OpenCV to reconstruct the rotation and translation from the generated essential matrix.
To test my code, I created two scenarios:
Scenario 1
In this scenario, I use two cameras that are at a 90degree angle to each other and observe four coplanar points:

When I run my python script:
essential_matrix_tests(
    r1=Rotation.from_euler("XYZ", (pi / 2, 0, 0)).as_matrix(),
    t1=np.array([[0], [-1], [4]], dtype=float),
    k1=np.array([[99, 0, 49.5],  # camera 1 intrinsics
                 [0, 99, 49.5],
                 [0, 0, 1]], dtype=float),
    r2=Rotation.from_euler("XYZ", (pi / 2, 0, pi / 2)).as_matrix(),
    t2=np.array([[0], [0], [3]], dtype=float),
    k2=np.array([[99, 0, 49.5],  # camera 2 intrinsics
                 [0, 99, 49.5],
                 [0, 0, 1]], dtype=float),
    Pw=np.array([[[-1], [0], [0], [1]],
                 [[1], [0], [0], [1]],
                 [[0], [-1], [0], [1]],
                 [[0], [1], [0], [1]]], dtype=float)
)

I get strange results:
...
-> determinant:
-0.0
-> eigen values:
[-0.+0.e+00j -1.+1.e-07j -1.-1.e-07j]
-> absolute eigen values:
[0. 1. 1.]
-> epipolar constraint for all points:
0.0
-> rotation (rotvec in degrees):
[  0. -90.   0.]
-> reconstructed rotation (rotvec in degrees):
[ -0. -90.   0.]
-> translation:
[-3. -1.  4.]
-> reconstructed translation:
[4. 1. 3.]

After checking that all the observed points are projected and transformed correctly, I'm stuck with two observations I can't explain:

The two non-zero eigenvalues are not equal, which contradicts one of the properties of $E$
Even though $E$ is not a proper essential matrix according to the first point, OpenCV was able to reconstruct the pose perfectly (even though, the translation vector seems to be in a different coordinate system)

Scenario 2
In this scenario I have two cameras with more realistic resolutions that look at the top and bottom of an upside-down house shaped point cloud.

With the following function parameters:
essential_matrix_tests(
    r1=Rotation.from_euler("XYZ", (-22.5, -45, 0), degrees=True).as_matrix(),
    t1=np.array([7.07106761, 0.85822177, 7.29818185])[..., np.newaxis],
    k1=np.array([[1280, 0, 639.5],
                 [0, 1280, 359.5],
                 [0, 0, 1]]),
    r2=Rotation.from_euler("XYZ", (22.5, 45, 0), degrees=True).as_matrix(),
    t2=np.array([-7.07106761, -0.85822177, 7.29818185])[..., np.newaxis],
    k2=np.array([[1280, 0, 639.5],
                 [0, 1280, 359.5],
                 [0, 0, 1]]),
    Pw=np.array([[-1.0, -1.0, 9.0, 1],
                 [1.0, -1.0, 9.0, 1],
                 [1.0, -1.0, 11.0, 1],
                 [-1.0, -1.0, 11.0, 1],
                 [-1.0, 1.0, 9.0, 1],
                 [1.0, 1.0, 9.0, 1],
                 [1.0, 1.0, 11.0, 1],
                 [-1.0, 1.0, 11.0, 1],
                 [-1.0, 2.0, 10.0, 1],
                 [1.0, 2.0, 10.0, 1]], dtype=float)[..., np.newaxis]
)

The results of this example are even worse:
...
-> determinant:
0.0
-> eigen values:
[-13.89880474   0.72723091  -0.        ]
-> absolute eigen values:
[13.898805  0.727231  0.      ]
-> epipolar constraint for all points:
0.0
-> rotation (rotvec in degrees):
[35.176 91.92   0.   ]
-> reconstructed rotation (rotvec in degrees):
[35.176 91.92   0.   ]
-> translation:
[14.142  1.716 14.596]
-> reconstructed translation:
[-14.142  -1.716  14.596]

Again, OpenCV was able to reconstruct the transformation from the essential matrix, but the eigenvalues are entirely different. This raises the question of why I'm not able to produce "valid" essential matrices with the eigenvalue property, using the well known formula, but still fulfill the epipolar constraint for all observed points and am able to reconstruct the pose using OpenCV. Am I misunderstanding the eigenvalue property?
